# Binary search using python and values checking

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I'm trying to implement a binary search algorithm in python, so  my goal was to implement three things:

the binary search (go to the middle, then go up or down and stuff)

a list that keeps track of all the used guesses so they don't repeat

two variables to determine the minimum and maximum based on the information the user giver (ex: the value is greater than 50)

I was able to do the binary search, but it alone is not very efficient, so I need to implement the other two for it to properly work. I'm currently stuck on the list thing.

there is my main function, called guesses

`def guesser(maximum, minimum):

```
global guess

rightOrNot = str(input(f"is you number {round(guess)}?[yes/no]"))[0]

if rightOrNot in "yY":

    print("thanks for playing")

    exit()

else:

    usedNumbers.append(guess)

    goHigherOrLower = str(input("is you number higher or lower?"))[0]

    if goHigherOrLower in "lL":

            if guess < maximum:

                maximum = guess

            guess = adjustGuess(guess, maximum, minimum, goHigherOrLower)

            guesser(guess, maximum)

    elif goHigherOrLower in "hH":

            if guess > minimum:

                minimum = guess

            guess = adjustGuess(guess, maximum, minimum, goHigherOrLower)

            guesser(guess, maximum)

    usedNumbers.append(guess)

print(usedNumbers)`
```

I tried to print the used numbers in the end, but [image]

apparently the numbers are not being appended and I can't figure out why. This adjust guess function in the middle is made to adjust the guess (lower or increase it and adjust so none used values are used again and it respects the maximum and minimum)

```
    if lowhigh in "hH":
    numberToAdjust += numberToAdjust/2
    while numberToAdjust in usedNumbers:
        numberToAdjust += 1
```

this is the function that treats the guess and checks if it is on the list. The 'hH' indicates that the user's number is higher than the anterior guess (there is another block of code for the lower one)

anyone has any idea on why my code is broken?

Comment: You are using recursion for repeating your code for each of the user's guesses, rather than a loop.  Each recursive call to your function has its own, independent set of local variables: appending to a list in one instance has absolutely no effect on the variable of the same name in other instances.

Comment: @jasonharper oh, that actually makes sense lol. I was thinking about the recursion because when I did similar appending with loops I never got a bug like this, thanks. I kind of prefer working with recursion instead of loops. Is there a way I can fix this easily? If not, it's ok, loops are also just fine!

Comment: Maybe you can try using a global list to make the recursion work?

Comment: @CtrlMj I added a "global usedNumbers" line and I got the same result